# Ajax, CORS, null domain

Tags: javascript, php, cors

Can I connect via ajax to a CORS-enabled (PHP) server from an html document open from the file system (no server / null domain)?  I would confirm this myself, but I do not currently have access to a server on which I could test this.

I have some half-developed code on a project that would need to be able to connect to a server via ajax even when opened from the file system, and I'd just like to confirm that this concept works before I spend more time finishing my work

Comment: Yes. Unless outer IP is blocked; you could roll up in there like a human agent. If you can load it via browser, you can call it via AJAX cors or not, just may take headers/auth's etc.

Comment: You don't need a separate server. Any localhost server will be sufficient for your test (since `file://` is a different origin than `http://localhost`). Or test with a public API online which you know accepts CORS requests. I'm pretty sure it's banned for security reasons though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as long as the server allows the AJAX request method and origin, specified in its `Access-Control` headers.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization"
```

To disable `Authorization` checks:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
```

You also need to disable web security checks for some browsers where you open the file URL, in Chrome for example:

```
$ google-chrome --disable-web-security
```

Safari has stricter requirements for CORS so maybe you will need to add more allowed headers (depending on your request). In Safari we need to `Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions` in the Safari Browser Developer menu.

Also worth mentioning that `<iframe>` CORS requests will be allowed even without disabling CORS in the browser since the element is sandboxed (cannot be queried from within the host URL).

Comment: I had added this `    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to my httpd.conf file, and was getting an error. I thought I just had an old version of Apache, but the problem was that I hadn't turned on the Headers module :) Anyway thank you for your answer this has made my morning!